# Change time allowed for server response in offline.js

Tags: javascript

I am using `offline.js` in a mobile web project.  In the specific environment I am running in, the script seems to be a little over-zealous in reporting that the connection to the server is lost.  How do I go about modifying it to allow the server a longer time to respond?

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? http://github.hubspot.com/offline/

Comment: Yes.  It didn't have anything regarding timeout.  Having now read Ori Dori's answer, I see that the timeout is a property of the XHR request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the check in `Offline.options` with the required `xhr`:

```
Offline.options = {
    checks : {
        xhr : {
            url : function () {
                return "/favicon.ico?_=" + ((new Date()).getTime());
            },
            timeout : 10000, // change this to the timeout you need
            type : 'HEAD'
        }
    }
};
```

Check the [source](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline/blob/master/js/offline.js) at line 28 for the defaults.
You can see the way to set the checks under the **Checking** header in the [documentation](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [this](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline):

> Options (any can be provided as a function), with their defaults:
>
> ```
> {
>   // Should we check the connection status immediatly on page load.
>   checkOnLoad: false,
>
>   // Should we monitor AJAX requests to help decide if we have a connection.
>   interceptRequests: true,
>
>   // Should we automatically retest periodically when the connection is down (set to false to disable).
>   reconnect: {
>     // **How many seconds should we wait before rechecking**.
>     initialDelay: 3,
>
>     // **How long should we wait between retries**.
>     delay: (1.5 * last delay, capped at 1 hour)
>   },
>
>   // Should we store and attempt to remake requests which fail while the connection is down.
>   requests: true,
>
>   // Should we show a snake game while the connection is down to keep the user entertained?
>   // It's not included in the normal build, you should bring in js/snake.js in addition to
>   // offline.min.js.
>   game: false
> }
> ```